# How to use implement drill-down in mxGraph?

Tags: java

i am using JGraph for a project.
I am facing a big problem and the documentation of mxGraph (java version) is not helping me.
I would like to implement the drill-down functionality but i don't know how.
Can somebody describe me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mxGraph.enterGroup(Object)` and `mxGraph.exitGroup(Object)`